# Set logic in one Observable? Angular

Tags: angular

When I send a form which is not valid, it is sent to me 2 times http post request.

```
<form [formGroup]="formG" (submit)="onSubmitForm()">
 <input type="text formControlName="userName">
 <button type="submit">
</form>
```

inside ts

```
   onSubmitForm() { 
    this.service.addUserName(this.formG.value).subscribe((res:any) => {
      console.log('succes response');
    }) 
  }
```

inside service:

```
  public addUserName(userName) { 
    return this.httpClient.httpPostGlobal<any[]>(`addNewUser/${userName}`, null);
  }
```

**httpPost** is a little complicated. Made as a global service.

inside global service for httpPostGlobal is ->

```
public httpPostGlobal<T>(path: string, data: any): Observable<HttpResponse<T>> {

    let postMetodData = (observer: Observer<HttpResponse<T>>) => {
        this.getTokenFromServiceData().subscribe(
            userToken => {
                let httpOptions = {
                    observe: 'response' as 'response',
                    headers: new HttpHeaders({
                        Authorization: ,
                        accept: 'application/json'
                    }),
                };

                this.http.post<T>(environment.url + path, data, httpOptions)
                    .pipe(
                        catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                            return throwError(err);
                        }))
                    .subscribe(
                        response => this.successCallback(response, observer),
                        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => this.errorCallback(error, observer)
                    );
            }
        );
    };

    let obs = new Observable<HttpResponse<T>>(postMetodData);
    return obs;
}
```

Inside this function is problem... probably catchError but i don't know.

The only problem is that it duplicates http request post 2 times. Everything else works. When added and when the response is 200 or 201 and everything else works. The only problem is when the form that is not valid is submitted and when the backend returns 422, it fires the same request 2 times and if I pressed submit only once on the form.

successCallback is only:

```
private successCallback<T>(response: HttpResponse<T>, observer: Observer<HttpResponse<T>>): void {
    if ((response.status === 200 || response.status === 204 || response.status === 201) &&
        (response.statusText === HttpService.OK || response.statusText === HttpService.NO_CONTENT
            || response.statusText === HttpService.CREATED)) {
        observer.next(response);
    } else {
        observer.error(response);
    }

    observer.complete();
}
```

Comment: Why dont you put several debugger; statements to see what is happening? Are you sure that you see 2 different API calls in a network tab in dev tools or just 2 errors in console?

Comment: i set up console.log in most places. I am never shown 2 console.log and always do 2 requests. I watching only network tab. api calls are identical same. One after another.

Answer (score 0):

There are few strange things here:

1. `Authorization: ,` This is empty?
2. `errorCallback` is called but we do not see the implementation?

Looking just at your code, i would say that the only scenario when 2 api calls are posted to a server is when

```
this.http.post<T>(environment.url + path, data, httpOptions)
```

is called twice. You can add a `console.log(1)` just before to see how many times is printed.

If that is a case then probably you have a value on stream:

```
this.getTokenFromServiceData()
```

that comes "again" when some call has failed.

Comment: private errorCallback<T>(response: HttpErrorResponse, observer: Observer<HttpResponse<T>>): void {
        observer.error(response);
        observer.complete();
    }

Comment: Authorization: is not empty... return token

Comment: getTOken is     private getToken() {
        return this.authService.getToken().pipe(map((token => {
            return this.authService.getScheme() + token;
        })));
    }

Comment: Did you put console log before this.http.post<T>(environment.url + path, data, httpOptions) ?

Comment: Yes. Only one is printed. I put console.log in whole app...

Comment: nowhere do I see that anything has been called twice other than http request.

Comment: hm... not having much idea what is happening. You can try to go in your developer tools in Chrome and click on each HTTP request and go to Initiator tab to see the calling stack. Also check if those two HTTP calls are exatly the same in dev tools (no redirects, same hTTP code, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You are subscribing to multiple events here, regardless of if the first one works or not. Instead you should put this logic into one Observable.

I also fix some issues, and used some typescript to clean things up.

```js
public httpPostGlobal<T>(path: string, data: any): Observable<HttpResponse<T>> {
  return this.getTokenFromServiceData().pipe(
    switchMap(userToken => {
      const httpOptions = {
        observe: 'response' as 'response', // this probably isnt needed as this is already the default value
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          Authorization: `${userToken}`,
          accept: 'application/json',  // this probably isnt needed as this is already the default value
        }),
      };
      return this.http.post<T>(`${environment.url}${path}`, data, httpOptions);
    }),
    map(response => this.successCallback(response, observer)),
    catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => this.errorCallback(error, observer)),
  );
}
```

Comment: what is observer here ? Cannot find name 'observer'.ts(2304) error

Comment: ts(2304) is a error that you get when trying to import files. check to see you dont have `require('observe')` in your code. Also i used the exact header you had in your example, i also added a note saying you probably dont need some of them, `observe` being one.

Comment: what is require('observe') ? how to import ?

Comment: i think you miss read my comment. I was saying that they error is, your file is trying to import something that doesn't exist. this is a different issue. I was trying to say, insure all your imports/requires are correct.

Comment: in my code (observer: Observer<HttpResponse<T>>) ... that part is missing here.

Comment: i am little refactor your code .. I don't have a request at the moment..I need that subscribe to subscribe to the request ..

Comment: You shouldn’t subscribe in this function, you should do that in the the component that is making the request. This pass back the observable and the main component can subscribe from there.